# In Elasticsearch Data folder What is the scenario which folder nodes/1 gets created?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are facing an issue w.r.t folder which elasticsearch uses for data. I can see I was getting data from *data/elasticsearch/nodes/0* folder before, now it changed to *data/elasticsearch/nodes/1*

Old data is still there in *data/elasticsearch/nodes/0* we were able to verify that by copying the data from *node/0* to *node/1*

Please help me on the reason why it is behaving like this and how to reproduce this issue. so we can avoid the same in future.

Comment: How you find out data is returned from which folder??

Comment: I used this command :
curl localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/fs?pretty 

This will respond the stats info which will show the fs.data.path also.

Comment: how many nodes you have in your cluster??

Comment: it is a single node setup.

Comment: you mentioned you copied the data from node/0 to node/1, whey you did that??

Comment: I want to verify that data not lost on the system. that was a workaround we tried to recover data.